# How to make specific parts of a text line indented properly?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I use python print() function to print component name, its current version and latest version as follows:

```
for component in component_list:

print("%s \t current ver: %s \t latest ver: %s" % (name, current_version, latest_version))
```

The component name can differ in its length, which makes the sentence parts not be indented properly.

```
bla      current ver: 0x05   latest ver: 0x05


blabla1      current ver: 0x06   latest ver: 0x06


blablablabla     current ver: 0x08   latest ver: 0x0e
```

How can I make the above printed as follows:

```
bla              current ver: 0x05   latest ver: 0x05


blabla1          current ver: 0x06   latest ver: 0x06


blablablabla     current ver: 0x08   latest ver: 0x0e
```

Thanks,

Comment: `"%20s" % string` will space the string over 20 characters, even if the string is less than 20 characters.

Comment: Have a careful read through the [Format Specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). Perhaps not the easiest to read, but it has all your information. It mostly uses the newer braces-style formatting, but that shouldn't really matter, as most examples can be easily translated to percent-style formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `maxLength` is the maximum length of the name in your list, e.g.:

```
# I don't know how you extract name from component so this might be incorrect
maxLength = max(len(component.name) for component in component_list)
```

Then you can use the following to correctly format your code:

```
print("{:{width}} \t current ver: {} \t latest ver: {}".format(
    name, current_version, latest_version, width = maxLength)
)
```

Explanation:

```
>>> '{:<20}'.format('Hello World!') # Add spaces to the right to reach 20 characters
'Hello World!        '
>>> '{:>20}'.format('Hello World!') # Add spaces to the left
'        Hello World!'
>>> '{:20}'.format('Hello World!') # Use default alignment for the type of object
'Hello World!        ' # For string it is left aligned
```

Then, instead of using a raw `20`, you can use another variable to specify the width:

```
>>> '{:<{width}}'.format('Hello World!', width = 20)
'Hello World!        '
```

Check [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) documentation for complete documentation of the *Format Specification Mini-Language*.

Comment: Align specs' e.g  {:<20}` specifies justification and width on individual fields.

Answer (score 0):

- Iterate over all the list to find the maximum length of the left component
- use this value (e.g. round it to the next 4 character) to determine the starting column for the second  component (say `n`)
- Iterate again over the list, this time printing the first component, `(n-len(first_component))` spaces and then the second component

Comment: This is a non-standard answer, sure, but a downvote is not warranted. Anyway, the standardish answer would be to use `str.format()`.